# For "post views" function, which of these two options is better?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies, view

Post views: initialized as 0, and is incremented when a user reads a post. If the user reads the same post, it should not be incremented.

To implement post view function, I thought of two options.

1. Each post has a table that lists all the users that have read the post. In PostController, the postview function would try to find the user in the table first, and if the user is not found, it increments the number of views.
2. Use cookies. Whenever a user reads a post, I give him a cookie that is specific to the post. For example, cookie[:postId] = 1. So the view function in the post controller can simply check if the user has a cookie for a particular post before incrementing the number of views.

I am not sure which option would be better. I think the second option is better if it's suitable because you can save memory in the database. But would this option be worse in terms of network traffic? I am not 100% sure if these two options are both valid, or which is better in terms of efficiency.

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Use (or get ideas from) Impressionist: https://github.com/charlotte-ruby/impressionist

Then you can get unique impressions on a record like so:

```
# only record impression if the request has a unique combination of type, id, and session
impressionist :unique => [:impressionable_type, :impressionable_id, :session_hash]
```